# Add Offset Y "-100px" when I click on an anchor and it scrolls me down to an element

Tags: javascript, smooth-scrolling

I need to add an offset of -100px when I click on a link that scrolls me down to a section. I have managed to make my scroll smooth , but i cannot make it to scroll with offsetY.

Here is my js code :

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

for (const link of links) {
  link.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const href = this.getAttribute("href");
  const offsetTop = document.querySelector(href).offsetTop;

  scroll({
    top: offsetTop,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
}
```

... and here is my html :

```
<a href ="#mysection">Go to section </a>
<p>this is some lorem</p>
<p>this is some lorem</p>
<p>this is some lorem</p>

<div id ="mysection"> The section that appears when i click on the anchor. I want an offset on this div so that when i click on anchor, it wil scroll me at the beggining of this section </div>
```

Comment: `offsetTop -= 100;`?

Comment: You can't use a href as a selector as it is. What you need is an attribute selector: `\`[href="${href}"]\``.

Comment: @Teemu the attribute selector doesn't work :(

Comment: @Liam offsetTop -=100 doesn't work

Comment: What does the console say? Any errors?

Comment: @Liam it works but it scrolls me to top -100 when i do that. I don't want to be scrolled to top -100, i want to be scrolled to a section.. and add -100px on scroll to that section.. so that i can see my whole section.

Comment: Right now the code works.. but it scrolls me to half of my section. And i want to be scrolled from the beggining. That's why i needed offsetY or some sort of.

Comment: Why don't you just get the reference to the element via `event.target` instead of the complex DOM query? Also, the attribute selector [works as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/p87vdws6/), if there's still something wrong with the code, it's `scroll` function causing troubles, not this what you've introduced in the question.

Comment: "_click on a link that scrolls me down to a section_" So, does this mean, that the element the link navigates, is the base you want to the offset being relative to? Please show the code for `scroll` function and the relevant markup (some links and some sections), so that we can see, how that element can be recognized. As it is, `href` attribute as a selector is considered as a tag selector, and there's no tag which would look like an URL.

Comment: @Teemu i added html to my js. So that you can see the full situtation.

Comment: `const offsetTop = document.querySelector(href).offsetTop;` should result in an error. There is no element with the id `mysection` there is only one with the id `#mysection`.

Comment: First of all, that needs to be `id ="mysection"`, without the `#` in that place. And second, it is _still_ unclear what you actually want here. Clicking that link would “jump” to the section without any JS already, and I don’t see why there would be any “offset” required here. How is https://jsfiddle.net/75codqb8/ _not_ behaving like you want it to, or what exactly is _different_ from this example in your specific situation?

Comment: Btw. for smooth scrolling you don't need javascript at all. You can enable that with CSS [`scroll-behavior: smooth;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) And if you need an offset you could solve that with some padding or margin.

Comment: Now the question is much better, but it still lacks the code for `scroll` function. Please add the code, or if the function is in a library, add a link to the library. Althought solutions introduced by CBroe and t.niese might resolve your problem.

Comment: I can't use margin top for offset for my case that's why i was looking for something with offset.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe thats what you looking for.
In my case , when I clicked on menu link I was dericted to section I need, but since I have Header fixed on top, my section have been covered.
So I added to my section one  with id="about-anchor" and styled it with position relative and top -85px;

See code snippets for details.

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
section {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

#hero-qnchor,
#about-qnchor,
#contact-anchor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -85px;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    padding: 0 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    transition: color 200ms ease, background-color 200ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <a href="#hero-qnchor">
                <li>Hero</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#about-qnchor">
                <li>About</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#contact-anchor">
                <li>Contact</li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section id="hero">
        <div id="hero-qnchor"></div>
        <p className="about-wrapper__info-text">
             Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero Hero
            </br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.
        </p>
    </section>
    <section id="about">
        <div id="about-qnchor"></div>
        <p className="about-wrapper__info-text">
             About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About About
            </br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.
        </p>
    </section>
    <section id="contact">
        <div id="contact-anchor"></div>
        <p className="about-wrapper__info-text">
             Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact
            </br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.</br>.
        </p>
    </section>
</div>
```